# What if first differencing and individual dummy variables produce different estimates?

Tags: econometrics, fixed-effects-model

I am replicating a paper where the authors use first-differencing to eliminate individual fixed effects.  In my replication I estimated the model (using the exact same data) using individual dummy variables instead of first-differencing.  I got a result that is the opposite sign and statistically significant.  I did not change anything else in the model.  Does this mean the model is wrong?  I'm not sure what to make of this.